# Visual Studio 2015 How to restore packages?

Tags: tfs, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

So my team mate commited some code in TFS and he added some new references. However these would not want to download even if the checkbox is checked insite the nuget package settings. So I tried deleting all the references from the solution explorer. How can I get them back as well as whatever my team mate commited to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`right click on solution>source control>get specific version` to undo changes.
If that doesn't bring your deleted files, you need to go to:

`Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation`, then check

> "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer"

checkbox.

Go to source control where your deleted files where located `right click>source control>get specific version`